# LocalStorage destructuring data in react javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

How to get this element in localStorage ?
[image]

Here I can console.log(product.priceHistory) but how to get its element price?

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let productFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem(id);
    setProduct(JSON.parse(productFromLocalStorage));
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div style={styles.container}>
      <h1 style={styles.title}>Product {product.name} View Page</h1>
      {console.log(product.priceHistory)}
      <Table product={product} />
      <Tabs data={data} />
    </div>
  );
```

Console.log(product.priceHistory) shows this:
[image]

Raw data:

> {"name":"table","ean":"eur","type":"furniture","weight":"21","color":"red","quantity":"8","price":"55","active":true,"priceHistory":[["555","2020-06-11T10:27:36.208Z"],["55","2020-06-11T10:28:44.392Z"],["55","2020-06-11T10:28:46.494Z"],["55","2020-06-11T10:28:47.382Z"],["55","2020-06-11T10:28:48.577Z"]]}

Full source code: https://pastebin.com/gJbkCLPh

Console.log(product)
[image]

ERROR:
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
ProductView

```
D:/talech/talech/src/Screens/Product.js:46
  43 | 
  44 |  return (
  45 |    <div style={styles.container}>
> 46 |      <h1 style={styles.title}>Product {product.name} View Page</h1>
     | ^  47 |      {console.log(product.priceHistory[0][0])}
  48 |      <Table product={product} />
  49 |      <Tabs data={data} />
```

Comment: `product.priceHistory[0][0]`?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov doesn't work TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Then, you're [probably](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/QWyNwEe?editors=0012) doing something wrong...

Comment: console.log(product.priceHistory[0][0]) I tried it my self, can't figure what's wrong

Comment: Added source code: https://pastebin.com/UaX3fNkC

Comment: I'm guessing, this line `let productFromLocalStorage = localStorage[id]` is the root cause, you're [supposed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage#Example) to do `localStorage.getItem()` instead

Comment: @Emilis, Can you try like ```console.log(product && product.priceHistory && product.priceHistory.data.priceHistory[0][0])``` ??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan product.priceHistory.data.priceHistory[0][0] i get ×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'priceHistory' of undefined

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov tried same result nothing changes

Comment: @Emilis, Then you should get the ```product``` itself undefined.. Are you sure you are getting data in ```product.priceHistory```? Did you tried as like ```product && product.priceHistory && ...```??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan YES I attached printScreen of my console.log

Comment: what u getting in this console?

`{console.log(product.priceHistory)}`

Comment: try `let productFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem[id];`  instead of `let productFromLocalStorage = localStorage[id];`

Comment: @NithishGandesiri done that, same result.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen look in description it's there

Comment: Can you check whether the `id` that you are getting from `params` is same as the `id` of the object being stored otherwise `localStorage.getItem` will give you null.

Comment: @NithishGandesiri id is good, I can print product.priceHistory so if id would be null or undefined it would not give me result. id comes from route const { id } = useParams();

Comment: Can u try consoling `{console.log(product.priceHistory[0])}` and share what's the result

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen plz look in my question at the bottom I attached error if I try to put {console.log(product.priceHistory[0])} error is the same Cannot read property '0' of undefined ProductView

Comment: @Emilis It'd be great if you'd make sandbox of your code so that anyone here could play around to get it sorted.

Comment: @ZainUlAbideen is pastebin ok? https://pastebin.com/gJbkCLPh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

priceHistory will be undefined on first render, until the useEffect setState is asynchronously called and a re-render is triggered with the new data loaded from localStorage loaded into the state

```
{console.log(product.priceHistory?.[0]?.[0])}
```

Using [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-benz-gplyo?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: It should show undefined for the first render, and then you'll see it later after the second render when the state updates.  Check to see if the codesandbox I have set up matches your code's structure.  I used your JSON string to set localStorage when the script starts.  Note: something has to trigger the `useEffect`, so if you update localStorage, you _must_ change `id` or some other prop/state to trigger render

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem)

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const localStorageMock = {
getItem: (key) => {
  return key === "1" ? null : JSON.stringify( {"name":"table","ean":"eur","type":"furniture","weight":"21","color":"red","quantity":"8","price":"55","active":true,"priceHistory":[["555","2020-06-11T10:27:36.208Z"],["55","2020-06-11T10:28:44.392Z"],["55","2020-06-11T10:28:46.494Z"],["55","2020-06-11T10:28:47.382Z"],["55","2020-06-11T10:28:48.577Z"]]})
}
}

const App = () => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const [id] = useState("2");
  
  useEffect(() => {
    let productFromLocalStorage = localStorageMock.getItem(id);
    setProduct(JSON.parse(productFromLocalStorage));
  }, [id]);
  
  return <div>
    {console.log(product && product.priceHistory)}
  </div>
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I use localStorage.getItem(id) but result is the same